# ViewModelScope is canceled permanently?

Tags: android, mvvm

I am trying to use MVVM in my latest Android app. I am also using coroutines. I have ViewModel, that is injected into Activity using koin. To run coroutines in my ViewModel I am using ViewModelScope. Then after Activity is finished, ViewModel is cleared, and I will run this activity again - viewModelScope is canceled since the beginning.

That's very odd. As viewModelScope should be... reseted somehow or something? Or maybe my viewModelScope isn't closing correctly?

Comment: You may wish to edit your question and provide a [mcve]. In particular, your Koin module that supplies the `ViewModel` would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

It would be helpful to see some code, but one possible thing to consider is - Are you injecting your ViewModel as a singleton with Koin?

`single { MyViewModel() }`

If so, this is your issue, as Koin is creating a single instance of your viewmodel and using this when you next load your activity. Change your Koin module to use the viewModel injection like so:

`viewModel { MyViewModel() }`

Comment: thanx a lot! it helped me soo much! Actually I was using dagger and i forgot to release the component)))